# Element in mulitple <xsl:for-each> loops does not display in table

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, transformation

I'm currently having an issue where the data in an XML is not displaying correctly in a table and gives me an empty cell.

My XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cursos.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE cursos SYSTEM "cursos.dtd">
<cursos>
    <curso codigoCurso="AA2000">
        <nombreCurso>Manejo Ofimatica</nombreCurso>
        <programa>
          <temas>
            <tema codigoTema="T001">
                <tituloTema>Introduccion</tituloTema>
            </tema>
            <tema codigoTema="T002">
                <tituloTema>Word</tituloTema>
                <impartidor>Jon Nieve</impartidor>
            </tema>
          </temas>
        </programa>
    </curso>
</cursos>
```

And im trying to get this info to display on a table that goes like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="cursos/curso">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="3"><xsl:value-of select="nombreCurso"/></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Codigo Tema</th>
              <th>Nombre del Tema</th>
              <th>Impartidor</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="programa/temas"/>
              <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@codigoTema"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="tituloTema"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="impartidor"/></td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that it's only displaying the cell and not displaying the actual data and I don't know why.
Here is a screenshot of the table as I see it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/plWz3.jpg

The Solution:

I had to add an `<impartidor>` for every single `<tema>` which made my XML look like this:

```
<programa>
          <temas>
            <tema codigoTema="M001">
                <tituloTema>Introduccion</tituloTema>
                <impartidor>Bob Iger</impartidor>
            </tema>
            <tema codigoTema="M002">
                <tituloTema>Tablets</tituloTema>
                <impartidor>Jorah Mormot</impartidor>
            </tema>
            <tema codigoTema="M003">
                <tituloTema>Smartphones</tituloTema>
                <impartidor>Ninja</impartidor>
            </tema>
          </temas>
        </programa>
```

And I fixed the XSLT because it was accidentally auto closing which makes it look like this:

```
<table>
          <xsl:for-each select="cursos/curso">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="3"><xsl:value-of select="nombreCurso"/></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Codigo Tema</th>
              <th>Nombre del Tema</th>
              <th>Impartidor</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="programa/temas/tema">
              <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@codigoTema"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="tituloTema"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="impartidor"/></td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
```

Comment: Second for each is self closed it is not reaching the element.

Comment: @AmrendraKumar Oh wow, I didn't see that.

Comment: If you find the solution please mark answer as accept.

Answer (score 1):

Check your second `<xsl:for-each>`, this is closed immediately. Furthermore you have to dive one level deeper, down to `<tema>`

Try something like this

```
    <xsl:for-each select="cursos/curso">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3"><xsl:value-of select="nombreCurso"/></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Codigo Tema</th>
          <th>Nombre del Tema</th>
          <th>Impartidor</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="programa/temas/tema">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@codigoTema"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="tituloTema"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="impartidor"/></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

The nesting loop is doing nothing and context is not matching and the Xpath you given for the loop is also need to update. you can use the bellow code for proper table conversion:

Check this code and hope you will find the answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">


        <xsl:template match="/">
            <html>
                <body>
                    <table border="1">
                        <xsl:for-each select="cursos/curso">
                            <tr>
                                <th colspan="3"><xsl:value-of select="nombreCurso"/></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Codigo Tema</th>
                                <th>Nombre del Tema</th>
                                <th>Impartidor</th>
                            </tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="programa/temas/tema">
                            <tr>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@codigoTema"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="tituloTema"/></td>
                                <td><xsl:value-of select="impartidor"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```